# Android Webview throws "err_SSL_VERSION_INTERFERENCE" when resumed after inactivity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

I am making an app which has a webview inside a fragment! The webview shows a https website and it works fine!
But when I use the app after sometime, it throws "err_SSL_VERSION_INTERFERENCE". The only way I can resume it is by force closing the app and restarting it.
Is there any way to handle this exception and reload the page?

The code I am using for the webview segment is this: -

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl(webUrl);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressDialog.show();
            if(newProgress==100){
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
        }
    });
}
```

Error log:

```
E/chromium: [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(947)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below this code worked for me.

```
 val webView = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.webview_payment) as WebView
    webView.isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = true;
    webView.loadUrl(requireArguments().getString("redirect_url")!!)

    val settings: WebSettings = webView.settings
    settings.allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true
    settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
    settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
    settings.setAppCacheEnabled(false)
    settings.domStorageEnabled = true
  //  webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()



    webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
            val url = request?.url.toString()

            view?.loadUrl(url)
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request)
        }


        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            webView.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            Log.e("CurrentUrl", "ur :" + url.toString())

          


            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
        }

        override fun onReceivedError(
            view: WebView,
            request: WebResourceRequest,
            error: WebResourceError
        ) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)
        }
    }
```